# Bounty statement in profile causes favorite star to be misaligned

Tags: support, design

Please check the location of the favorite star icon for the first question in the screenshot below. There is an issue when the bounty statement is there. This CSS issue occurs on Chrome, Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion).

[image]

Comment: What is the red text in the screenshot?

Comment: @Tim Is that a hint?  ;)

Comment: @Chris No, I haven't seen the text before myself, so I wasn't sure what it was doing there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be mistaken, but I imagine that the position of the fav star icon is based on the position of the line *above* each question. The text "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" is pushing that line up and the fav star icon with it. Try checking the results on other browsers: if they are the same, this is probably by design; if they are different, this may be something that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Well, the entire list should be clearing the text anyway, so I think it's a minor styling bug either way.